# In RHEL7 is it possible to allow only some users to create ssh tunnels

Tags: rhel, users, ssh-tunneling, sshd

I want to setup a RHEL7 host that will allow a few people to ssh in. Let say 10 people will be able to access the box via ssh. Of those 10 people I only want 3 to be able to create a tunnel to other resources behind the firewall via a ssh tunnel. Is this possible?

I know I can use AllowUser and AllowGroup so that only the 10 people can ssh into the host. In I can leave AllowTcpForwarding on, but that would give everyone the ability to create ssh tunnels. I need only allow the 3 approved users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in your `sshd_config` file should do what you want:

```
AllowTcpForwarding off
...
Match user user1,user2,user3
    AllowTcpForwarding on
```

This will permit TCP forwarding for the three listed users.

See [sshd_config Match](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Match) for more details about how the `Match` directive works and which options can be set in a match block.